# Можно ли конфигурировать cucumber-js?

Tags: javascript, selenium, тестирование, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Ранее писал тесты на `java`, но возникла потребность в том, чтобы писать их на `js`.

Чтобы задать "кастомный" путь до фич или до `step_definitions`-файлов - в `java` не возникало никаких проблем. В `cucumber-js` же, проблема актуальна, точнее в документации о возможности конфигурирования путей нет ни слова.

Предлагаемая структура разработчиками:

```
features/
  test.feature
  support/
    world.js
    hooks.js
  step_definitions/
    test.js
```

Желаемая структура:

```
src/
  features/
    test/
      test.feature   # Сценарий
      test.steps.js  # "Шаги" для сценари
      test.js        # Объект страницы со всеми методами для "шагов"
  helpers/
    hooks.js
```

Соответственно, нужна возможность переопределить пути для `steps_definitions`-файлов, без использования сторонних инструментов (`wdio`, `protractor` и тд) для запуска тестов.

Запуск произвожу так:

Хелпер для инициализации драйвера:

```
'use strict';

const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
  chrome = require('chromedriver'),
  { setWorldConstructor } = require('cucumber');

const driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

module.exports = { driver };
```

Тестовая фича:

```
#local-run
Feature: Работоспособность поиска google

  Scenario: Поиск работает
    Given Открыли страницу google
    When Ввели поисковой зарос
      | Tomato   |
      | Cucumber |
      | Cabage   |
    Then Поиск выдал результаты
```

"Шаги" для тестовой фичи:

```
'use strict';

const { defineSupportCode } = require('cucumber');

    defineSupportCode(({ Given, When, Then, setDefinitionFunctionWrapper }) => {
      setDefinitionFunctionWrapper(() => {
        this.Given('Открыли страницу google', function (callback) {
          callback.pending();
        });

        this.When('Ввели поисковой зарос', function (callback) {
          callback.pending();
        });

        this.Then('Поиск выдал результаты', function (callback) {
          callback.pending();
        });
      })
    });
```

Объект страницы пустой, поэтому его не привожу, по той причине, что тесты не запускаются в принципе, т.е., фичу видно, но шагов нет.

Запускаю через `cucumber.js` в проекте.

Пробовал делать "стандарную" структуру приведенную в доках - все равно не работает, даже с кодом, приведенным там.

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите как вы запускаете тесты

Comment: @MikhailVaysman обновил описание.

Comment: попробуйте указать директории используя ключ `-r`. ключ `-r` можно использовать несколько раз для указания нескольких директорий.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman спасибо. Оказалось, все значительно проще - стрелочных функций вообще быть не должно в описании шагов, тк теряется ожидаемый контекст.